# Saving local storage is being flaky - Cypress

Tags: javascript, local-storage, cypress

I saw some other posts about local storage but they all relate to tokens and login.

We have an iframe that gets created and pops in from the right on our site upon first visit, I'm trying to keep this iframe from ever opening. A dev put an identifier in place for me to tell it's my Cypress test and to not fire the iframe but it's flaky.

I am using the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands to handle my local storage.

This is in my Command file:
`import "cypress-localstorage-commands";`

In my test, I have the following:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
        cy.setLocalStorage('is_cypress_test', 'true');
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        cy.saveLocalStorage();
    })
```

However, this frequently fails and the iframe opens. When it works, it also prints out to console that Cypress was detected (this is something added on our sites code to verify it was working).

Here is the basic look of my test.

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

describe(`it browses to xxxx`, () => {
    // sets up service cookie to preserve session
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
        preserve: 'foo',
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.setLocalStorage('is_cypress_test', 'true');
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        cy.saveLocalStorage();
    })

    it(`should log in via a POST, and browse xxx`, () => {
        cy.serviceLoginByCSRF(Cypress.env('user_name'), Cypress.env('password'));
        cy.visit('/#/asitepage');
    });
    
    describe(`it checks all xxxxx`, () => {

        it(`should verify xxxxxx`, () => {
            cy.get('h3').should('be.visible').invoke('text').then(data => {
                let regex = /\n|\*|Back/g;
                cy.textCleanup(data, regex).should('eq', 'bar');
            });
        });
     });

     describe(`it checks all yyyy`, () => {

        it(`should verify yyyy`, () => {
            cy.get('h3').should('be.visible').invoke('text').then(data => {
                let regex = /\n|\*|Back/g;
                cy.textCleanup(data, regex).should('eq', 'foo');
            });
        });
     });
});
```

Beamer code

```
<!-- Beamer for product updates -->
<script>
    var beamer_config = {
        product_id: "foobar",
        selector: "#beamer",
        user_email: 'example@test.blogspot.gov',
        user_firstname: 'Hank',
        user_lastname: 'Williams',
        filter: 'production',
        onopen: function(){
            // localStorage.setItem("is_cypress_test", "true") --  is test
            if(localStorage.getItem("is_cypress_test")){
                console.log("Skipping beamer load for Cypress");
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://asite.js" defer="defer"></script>
<!-- // Beamer for product updates -->
```

I'm wondering if I'm setting this in the wrong way, or wrong area?

Any help, or notes on how best to use this so it will always have that in localStorage before every test would be greatly appreciated.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: same thing, since starting using localStorage as storage place for tokens, with cypress-localstorage-commands or with own commands, tests became flaky 

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, what fixed it for me was adding the following code to `commands.js`:

```
Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
  return;
}
```